# Why docker container already set network_mode:"host" and the public still can access from "http://ip:port"

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, port

I try to make a architecture like this:

1. docker_container_1 nginx: expose to public (network_mode:"bridge", port:80)
2. docker_container_2 web_serverI: as internal service (network_mode:"host", port:8080)
3. docker_container_2 web_serverII: as internal service (network_mode:"host", port:8081)

---

```yaml
upstream server-i {
    server 172.17.0.1:8080;
}

upstream server-ii {
    server 172.17.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /service-i {
        proxy_pass http://server-i;   
    }

    location /service-ii {
        proxy_pass http://server-ii;   
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

- i already set service i and ii network_mode:"host"
- than i use "docker ps" to check, only nginx PORTS show
  0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, and other has nothing.
- and i also use "docker stats" to check, NET I/O of all container only nginx has value other is zero.
- **and i found that still can access server_i server-ii from outside use: http://ip:port(8080 and 8081)**
  how can do ? do i miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `network_mode: host`, it disables all of Docker's networking functionality for that container.  You can't remap a container port or prevent it from being visible on the host; you can't use the normal Docker inter-container networking to connect between containers.  Your host-networking containers, from a network point of view, are indistinguishable from a non-Docker process running directly on the host.

**Host networking is almost never necessary.**  In some very unusual cases -- if your service has thousands of ports it listens on, if you've measured the Docker NAT overhead to be significant with very-high-volume traffic -- it can get around some limitations of the Docker networking system.  In almost all practical cases you should use the default (bridged) networking, and publish specific ports if you need them to be accessible from outside Docker space.

You should:

- Disable host networking on all of your containers; use the standard bridge networking instead.  (In a non-Compose context, you will need to `docker network create` a network with default settings.)
- Update your Nginx configuration to use the other containers' names as host names; `server docker_container_2 web_serverI:8080`.  See for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for additional details.
- If you don't want the back-end containers to be visible from outside of Docker space, remove their Compose `ports:` configuration or `docker run -p` option.  Inter-container communication will still work without this.

Comment: i go it !!!!!!! very thank you ~
but i'm not use {container_name} : {port} to access ther inter-container, it not works for me.
i'm use "docker network inspect bridge" to check server-i's ipv4 (172.17.0.x)
than i config nginx to access through the inter-container's ipv4 and finally success !!!!

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to look up or directly use those IP addresses.  If you're using plain Docker, the `docker run --name` of the container should be usable as a host name by other containers on the same `docker run --net` (and you must `docker network create` a network and assign all of the containers to it; Compose does this automatically, but not `docker run`).

Comment: Ok i will try it later, thank you a lot ! really helpful